# 400 BAD REQUEST while sending an HTTP request using wamp localhsot

Tags: api, http, wamp, rfid

I am a student doing an internship as part of my college course, and I'm having a problem with using WAMP during sending an HTTP request.
I'm working on an RFID project with nodemcu8266 using arduino IDE, and I've to scan the tags and send the ID (ID of the card or the tag that the rfid scans) into my website using WAMP localhost server.

But after compiling the code I receive that problem '400 BAD REQUEST AS IT SHOWN BELOW'

here's my code for Arduino IDE:

```
//*******************************libraries********************************
//RFID-----------------------------

    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <MFRC522.h>

//NodeMCU--------------------------
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
//************************************************************************

    #define SS_PIN  D2  //D2
    #define RST_PIN D1  //D1

//************************************************************************
`MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);` // Create MFRC522 instance.
//************************************************************************
/* Set these to your desired credentials. */
const char *ssid = "..";
const char *password = "Nsssss*";
const char* device_token  = "115f2dbcafdb111d ";

    //************************************************************************
    String URL = "http://192.168.1.105/rfidattendance/getdata.php"; //computer IP or the server domain
    String getData, Link;
    String OldCardID = "";
    unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
    //************************************************************************
    void setup() {
      delay(1000);
      Serial.begin(115200);
      SPI.begin();  // Init SPI bus
      mfrc522.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522 card
      //---------------------------------------------
      connectToWiFi();
    }
    //************************************************************************
    void loop() {
      //check if there's a connection to Wi-Fi or not
      if(!WiFi.isConnected()){
        connectToWiFi();    //Retry to connect to Wi-Fi
      }
      //---------------------------------------------
      if (millis() - previousMillis >= 15000) {
        previousMillis = millis();
        OldCardID="";
      }
      delay(50);
      //---------------------------------------------
      //look for new card
      if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
        return;//got to start of loop if there is no card present
      }
      // Select one of the cards
      if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
        return;//if read card serial(0) returns 1, the uid struct contians the ID of the read card.
      }
      String CardID ="";
      for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
        CardID += mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i];
      }
      //---------------------------------------------
      if( CardID == OldCardID ){
        return;
      }
      else{
        OldCardID = CardID;
      }
      //---------------------------------------------
    //  Serial.println(CardID);
      SendCardID(CardID);
      delay(1000);
    }
    //************send the Card UID to the website*************
    void SendCardID( String Card_uid ){
      Serial.println("Sending the Card ID");
      if(WiFi.isConnected()){
        HTTPClient http;    //Declare object of class HTTPClient
        //GET Data
        getData = "?card_uid=" + String(Card_uid) + "&device_token=" + String(device_token); // Add the Card ID to the GET array in order to send it
        //GET methode
        Link = URL + getData;
        http.begin(Link); //initiate HTTP request   //Specify content-type header
        
        int httpCode = http.GET();   //Send the request
        String payload = http.getString();    //Get the response payload
    
    //    Serial.println(Link);   //Print HTTP return code
        Serial.println(httpCode);   //Print HTTP return code
        Serial.println(Card_uid);     //Print Card ID
        Serial.println(payload);    //Print request response payload
    
        if (httpCode == 200) {
          if (payload.substring(0, 5) == "login") {
            String user_name = payload.substring(5);
        //  Serial.println(user_name);
    
          }
          else if (payload.substring(0, 6) == "logout") {
            String user_name = payload.substring(6);
        //  Serial.println(user_name);
            
          }
          else if (payload == "succesful") {
    
          }
          else if (payload == "available") {
    
          }
          delay(100);
          http.end();  //Close connection
        }
      }
    }
    //********************connect to the WiFi******************
    void connectToWiFi(){
        WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);        //Prevents reconnection issue (taking too long to connect)
        delay(1000);
        WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
        Serial.print("Connecting to ");
        Serial.println(ssid);
        WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
        
        while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
          delay(500);
          Serial.print(".");
        }
        Serial.println("");
        Serial.println("Connected");
      
        Serial.print("IP address: ");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  //IP address assigned to your ESP
        
        delay(1000);

}
```

//=======================================================================

And the OUTPUT  is:

```
    16:28:00.789 -> Connecting to ..
    16:28:01.398 -> .......
    16:28:05.195 -> Connected
    16:28:05.195 -> IP address: 192.168.1.103
    16:28:08.101 -> Sending the Card ID
    16:28:08.101 -> 400
    16:28:08.101 -> 511749228
    16:28:08.101 -> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    16:28:08.101 -> <html><head>
    16:28:08.101 -> <title>400 Bad Request</title>
    16:28:08.101 -> </head><body>
    16:28:08.101 -> <h1>Bad Request</h1>
    16:28:08.101 -> <p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
    16:28:08.101 -> </p>
    16:28:08.148 -> <hr>
    16:28:08.148 -> <address>Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) PHP/7.4.26 Server at localhost Port 80</address>
    16:28:08.148 -> </body></html>
    16:28:08.148 ->
```